# The spring configuration client ignores active profile when sending request to configuration service

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-cloud

I'm creating a configuration server using spring cloud and when I'm trying to get my configuration info from git using `http://localhost:8071/licensing-service/dev` it works perfectly.

But when I specify the active profile `dev` in my configuration-client application
it sends request on `http://localhost:8071/licensing-service/default` where as it should be sending request on `http://localhost:8071/licensing-service/dev`.

Here is the debug info from configuration-client:

```
2022-08-03 01:44:11.999  INFO 11828 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8071
    2022-08-03 01:44:12.000 DEBUG 11828 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET http://localhost:8071/licensing-service/default
    2022-08-03 01:44:12.003 DEBUG 11828 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
    2022-08-03 01:44:12.677 DEBUG 11828 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
    2022-08-03 01:44:12.678 DEBUG 11828 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment]
    2022-08-03 01:44:12.679  INFO 11828 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=licensing-service, profiles=[default], label=null, version=a846a28be97b432d11b0ec2a9476fa3c933ac5fc, state=null
    2022-08-03 01:44:12.680  INFO 11828 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-https://github.com/DaveySC/config.git/file:C:\Users\hrisa\AppData\Local\Temp\config-repo-12695370095836324476\licensing-service.yaml'}]
    2022-08-03 01:44:12.687  INFO 11828 --- [           main] c.e.l.LicensingServiceApplication        : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
    2022-08-03 01:44:12.687 DEBUG 11828 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.example.licensingsevice.LicensingServiceApplication,class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener$BootstrapMarkerConfiguration
    2022-08-03 01:44:12.708  INFO 11828 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8071
    2022-08-03 01:44:12.708  INFO 11828 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Located environment: name=licensing-service, profiles=[dev], label=null, version=a846a28be97b432d11b0ec2a9476fa3c933ac5fc, state=null
    2022-08-03 01:44:12.709 DEBUG 11828 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@50d3bf39
    2022-08-03 01:44:13.482  INFO 11828 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
    2022-08-03 01:44:13.495 DEBUG 11828 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.AutoConfigurationPackages        : @EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the package 'com.example.licensingsevice'. Automatic @Repository and @Entity scanning is enabled.
    2022-08-03 01:44:13.538  INFO 11828 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 46 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
    2022-08-03 01:44:13.750  INFO 11828 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=ed5de582-c803-356a-a378-fc5af6eb571e
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.113 DEBUG 11828 --- [           main] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\hrisa\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.2\spring-boot-2.7.2.jar
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.113 DEBUG 11828 --- [           main] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\hrisa\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.2\spring-boot-2.7.2.jar
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.113 DEBUG 11828 --- [           main] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be ignored.
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.133  INFO 11828 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.141  INFO 11828 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.142  INFO 11828 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.295  INFO 11828 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.295 DEBUG 11828 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.295  INFO 11828 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1586 ms
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.390 ERROR 11828 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webMvcMetricsFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/simple/SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourcePoolMetadataMeterBinder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/jdbc/DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration$DataSourcePoolMetadataMetricsConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourcePoolMetadataMeterBinder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.410  INFO 11828 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.419  WARN 11828 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    2022-08-03 01:44:14.443 DEBUG 11828 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
```

Here is the main class of this server, pom and bootstrap.yml

```
package com.example.configurationserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;


    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableConfigServer
    @RefreshScope
    public class ConfigurationServerApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ConfigurationServerApplication.class, args);
        }
    
    }
```

pom.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>configuration-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>configuration-server</name>
    <description>configuration-server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configuration-server
  profiles:
    active: git
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          default-label: main
          uri: https://github.com/DaveySC/config.git
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        url: http://localhost:8080

server:
  port: 8071

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

Here are the client files: 
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>licensing-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>licensing-service</name>
    <description>licensing-sevice</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: licensing-service
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:http://localhost:8071
  profiles:
    active: dev
debug: true
```

And here is the exception i get:

```
description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles dev are currently active).
```

What should i do to make my app send request on the url that depends on the active profile client app?

Comment: spring.config.import and bootstrap are mutually exclusive. Pick one or the other

Comment: @spencergibb I've used this configuration: spring.cloud.config.uri: http://configserver:8071 instead spring.config.import but it still doesn't work